# Setting next and previous href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I am facing some problem what i have now is there are images render in a div and and there anchor tag inside div when user clicks on image
an overlay screen will open where i have to display pdf files i have used TouchPdf plugin now what i want is there will be arrows buttons on overlay screen which will navigate to next pdf file and displayed on overlay screen.I am getting difficulty in achieveing this Thanks All

this how images are rendered

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <div class="image-div-conents">
       <h3 class="circle">BI</h3>
           <div  class="doc-name-date">
                  <!-- <ul class="list-inline"> -->
                       <span class="bill">Bill</span>
                           <span  class="bill">2-02-2017</span>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <a  href="#">
                                <img  height="300px" class="img-responsive" src="http://i156.photobucket.com/albums/t20/warjhenz/1000x1000.gif" alt="">
                                <div class="validitity"><span>Validitity: Forever</span></div>
                            </a>
                    </div>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <div class="image-div-conents">
       <h3 class="circle">BI</h3>
           <div  class="doc-name-date">
                  <!-- <ul class="list-inline"> -->
                       <span class="bill">Bill</span>
                           <span  class="bill">2-02-2017</span>
                            <!-- </ul> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <a  href="#">
                                <img  height="300px" class="img-responsive" src="http://i156.photobucket.com/albums/t20/warjhenz/1000x1000.gif" alt="">
                                <div class="validitity"><span>Validitity: Forever</span></div>
                            </a>
                    </div>
```

this will continue and images are rendered horizontally

What i have tried is--

Add click event

```
$('.thumb a').on('click',function(){
 alert($(this).attr('href'));
 alert($(this).index());
});
```

but index is always 1 for each href as there are seprate div's and there is only anchor tag inside it.

Comment: which part of the HTML will repeat? I see only one a in your example, can you put more so that we get a complete picture

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed that above div contains one a tag above div will repeat and have other anchor tag and so on...see edit

Comment: ok good, what do you want to do onclick?? Please mention more details, I see people are downvoting your question, you need to tell what you want to acheive

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed have you ever image galllery there is next and previous button there to navigate to next image or previous image same i am trying to do with pdf files so when user click on image whait i am trying is to set next and previous hrefs on next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a topmost parent element which has all the divs
You can create a div

`<div class="parent> all your divs etc </div>`

```
$('.thumb a').on('click',function(){
 alert($(this).parentsUntil("thumb").index()); //Here the index will be the clicked index. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

The problem is that tha click event is on `a` tag and `#` takes to top of the page.You should always use `javascript:void(0)`.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```